# javascript heading as variable not using PHP

Tags: javascript, html

The problem is simple: I want to show a different heading depending on an internal variable in javascript, using NVD3. I've tried different things, learnt how `<title>` works and used it, but I could not get to the point. This is a very simplified version of the code:

```
<body>
<h1> [Here I want show some the content of the variable myheading] </h1>
</body>
```

```js
myheading= "This is the head of a specific plot";
```

I hope the answer is not too obvious, I've been looking for it for a while...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<h1 id="target">PlaceholderText</h1>
```

```
document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = myheading;
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. I did not know about .innerHTML

Comment: @RoToRa what would be your suggestion then? Why do you say it looks like a bad solution to a bigger problem? The problem was solved exactly as expected with `innerHTML`